# Chartjs break line for axes tick labels text

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

[image]

I'm trying to allow breaks on spaces for the labels of my data object. I've looked through configuration options on the Chartjs docs [tick configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration) to either allow line breaks or the ability to add a CSS class where I can handle this with break-word rules.

Data structure object:

```
{
    labels: ["Arts Languages and Communication", "Science, Techology and Health", "Business", "Society and Education"],
    datasets: [{label: "Fall 2014", data: [0,0,0,0]}...]
}
```

Options object:

```
{
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{ ticks: { /* no available options from docs */ } }]
    }
}
```

Desired outcome:

Words will break on spaces:

```
Arts Language
and Communication
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want your xAxis label to wrap text then you need to pass the data in this format `labels: [['LONG', 'LONG', 'LONG', 'LABEL'], "Blue", ['YELLOW', 'LONG'], "Green Green", "Purple", "Orange"]`

So in your case -> `labels:[['Arts Language', 'and Communication'], 'nextLabel', 'otherLabel']`

See a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzo5g01n/11/

Answer (score 0):

> If you want your xAxis label to wrap text then you need to pass the data in this format labels: [['LONG', 'LONG', 'LONG', 'LABEL'], "Blue", ['YELLOW', 'LONG'], "Green Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
>
> So in your case -> labels:[['Arts Language', 'and Communication'], 'nextLabel', 'otherLabel']
>
> See a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzo5g01n/11/

Adding auto-labels wrap:

```js
    ticks: { 
        callback: val => [val.slice(x,y), val.slice(y)], 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.
Here's what I did:

```
const labels = ["label1","label2","label3"];
ticks: {
    autoSkip: false,
    maxRotation: 0,
    callback: (value: any, index: any, values: any) => {
        let label = labels[value];
        if(label == null){
            return '';
        }
        if (label.length > 15) {
            label = label.substring(0, 15);
            label += '..';
        }
            return label;
    },
},
```

Labels is your x values.
This tick configuration, along with maxRotation and autoSkip, makes your xLabels end with ellipsis if they're too big.
E.g.: If the label is "Arts Languages and Communication", it should become "Arts Languages.."
You can still see the full label with the tooltip.